# MIT OCW 6.0001 pset 1b, calculate the months of saving required.3 tests, first is correct, the other two are 1 month more than my code gives, why?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, raise

```
#Code
'''

annual_salary = float(input('What is your starting annual salary?'))
monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
portion_saved = float(input('What percentage of your salary will you save each month(in decimals)?'))
Total_cost = float(input('How much is your dream home?'))
semi_annual_raise = float(input('What is your raise every 6 months(in decimals)?'))
portion_down_payment = 0.25*Total_cost
r = 0.04
current_savings = 0
months = 0
while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    months += 1
    if months % 6 == 0:
        monthly_salary += semi_annual_raise*monthly_salary
    current_savings += portion_saved*monthly_salary + current_savings*r/12
print('Number of months:', months)
```

#Tests
'''

```
      1:Enter your starting annual salary:  120000
        Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:  .05 
        Enter the cost of     your dream home:  500000
        Enter the semi­annual raise, as a decimal:  .03
        Number of months:  142

      2:Enter your starting annual salary:  80000
        Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:  .1 
        Enter the cost of your dream home:  800000
        Enter the semi­annual raise, as a decimal:  .03
        Number of months:  159

      3:Enter your starting annual salary:  75000
        Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:  .05 
        Enter the cost of your dream home:  1500000
        Enter the semi­annual raise, as a decimal:  .05
        Number of months:  261
```

here are the 3 tests, please help
the last 2 give 158 and 260 respectively for my codes results
it is an algorithm to calculate the months needed to save to pay a houses downpayment in accordance to salary, semi-annual raise, amount to save monthly, and a return on investments.

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Yeah I’ve done everything the code isn’t wrong it’s just that it’s not returning the correct value for the last two tests, is there anything wrong with my placement of the if statement within the while loop?

Comment: Doesn't _the code isn’t wrong_ contradict _it’s not returning the correct value for the last two tests_ ?

Answer (score 0):

#Code

```
annual_salary = float(input('What is your starting annual salary?'))
monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
portion_saved = float(input('What percentage of your salary will you save each month(in decimals)?'))
Total_cost = float(input('How much is your dream home?'))
semi_annual_raise = float(input('What is your raise every 6 months(in decimals)?'))
portion_down_payment = 0.25*Total_cost
r = 0.04
current_savings = 0
months = 0
while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    current_savings += portion_saved*monthly_salary + current_savings*r/12
    months += 1
    if months % 6 == 0:
        monthly_salary += semi_annual_raise*monthly_salary
print('Number of months:', months)
```

#misplacement of the months+=1 caused the error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're salary increase happens *before* your savings accrue interest. The assignment says to have the increase happen *after* the 6th month.