# MIT OCW 6.0001 pset1 part B

Tags: python

semi_annual_raise is the new thing. it is to be added in the monthly salary after every 6 months.

the o/p needed is 142 months but it comes out as 183 months as if the if condition does not exist.
the input values are 120000, .03, 500000, .05  in order of the prompts.

```
annual_salary     = float(input('Your starting annual salary : '))
semi_annual_raise = float(input('Your semi-annual salary raise (express in a decimal) : '))
total_cost        = float(input('The cost of your dream home : '))
portion_saved     = float(input('The portion of salary you want to be saved (express in a decimal) : '))

portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
r = 0.04
monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12

num_months = 0
current_savings = 0
while current_savings <= portion_down_payment:
    current_savings += current_savings * r / 12 + monthly_salary * portion_saved
    num_months += 1
    if num_months / 6 == 0:
        monthly_salary += monthly_salary * semi_annual_raise
        current_savings += current_savings * r / 12 + monthly_salary * portion_saved
print('Number of months =',num_months)
```

Comment: Regarding MIT OpenCourseWare (OCW) 6.0001 "Introduction to Computer Science and Programming in Python" ProblemSet 1 B, what is your question here?

Comment: "As if the for loop doesnt exist" – it doesn't exist in fact.

Comment: Does 105 is the answer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have an annual interest rate of 4%. The monthly multiplier is therefore 1.04 ** (1 / 12)

The problem is due to a lack of understanding of how compound interest is calculated and not a Python issue *per se*

So:

```
annual_salary     = 120000
semi_annual_raise = 0.03 # 3%
total_cost        = 500000
portion_saved     = 0.05 # 5%

portion_down_payment = total_cost / 4
r = 1.04 ** (1 / 12)
monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12
num_months = 0
current_savings = 0
while current_savings <= portion_down_payment:
    if (num_months := num_months + 1) % 6 == 0:
        monthly_salary *= 1 + semi_annual_raise
    current_savings *= r # add interest
    current_savings += monthly_salary * portion_saved
print('Number of months =', num_months)
```

**Output:**

```
142
```

Comment: Just for the records, one may also have a look into an other answer to [MIT OCW 6.0001 Pset 1b, Calculate the months of saving required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64562695/6771046).

Comment: @U880D Two people with the same problem or one person with multiple guises?

Comment: The question is from an open university course, a kind of home work for students. So questions are coming up sometimes regarding it. Some students taking the course might have questions, so, different people, but same question.